# Windows and macOS zipping differences?

Tags: windows, macos, zip

We need to submit data to a 3rd party and we are planning to automate it.

Their instructions are simple.

- Put the data in a spreadsheet file.
- Zip it (using Windows).
- Upload to their server.

Seems easy? But no.

We are using macOS to zip the spreadsheet file but their system doesn't seem to accept it. Their instructions explicitly state that you must use Windows to zip the file.

Here is what it looks like on Windows.

[image]

Here is what we are doing on macOS.

[image]

The zip file created on Windows works on their end but the one on macOS is not. We are using macOS at work so it will be hard to use Windows every time just to zip a file.

Are there differences in methods used on Windows and macOS zipping? Is there any way to zip a file like what it does on Windows on macOS?

Comment: What error are they getting?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure, they just tell us to use Windows to zip the file.

Comment: I can't remember ever having a problem unzipping a file from Mac on Windows. Or Linux, for that matter. Have you tried unzipping one of your Mac files on Windows?

Comment: @MetalMikester I just tried it myself. Compress in Finder on MacOS 11.3. Extract using Windows Explorer on Windows 10. No issues whatsoever. (Of course on Windows you can simply ignore the resource fork info in the __MACOSX sub-folder.)

Comment: Is the receiver using an automated script to unpack these zip-files ? In that case the presence of an unexpected sub-folder in the zip (the MacOS resource fork information) may throw them off if the script only expects a single file the zip-file.

Comment: @Tonny Yeah, I guess they don't know that they can just ignore that file. Your answer with the command-line alternative would take care of that without them having to deal with Windows just for this task.

Answer (score 2):

The will likely be apple double/resource fork info zipped in with it, but that's merely "untidy" & should in no way prevent them from unzipping it.
They may see such as

```
__MACOSX
    ._file.xlsx  
file.xlsx
```

after unzipping. If unzipped on another Mac this info is invisible & at unzip is wrapped back into the file. Losing that extra data is typically unimportant.

Such as [BetterZip](https://macitbetter.com) [paid] & [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) [donationware - free direct DL, paid App Store] can be told to exclude that extraneous Apple-specific info.

Using Keka as an example, once the 'exclude Mac resource forks' box is checked, zipping is just drag & drop.

[image]  [image]

This results in a clutter-free extract in Windows

[image]

as opposed to using the Finder to zip

[image]

Comment: The MacOS resource fork will be in a subfolder called __MACOSX (2 leading underscores) inside the zip-file and will consist of a file called  ._filename  (dot underscore) for each filename stored in the zip-file. You can safely ignore that sub-folder and its content under Windows.

Comment: I fixed the hierarchy - it's still harmless 'untidy' data & should cause absolutely zero issues. tbh, if it does, then it's the fault of the extract method. I'd just use the Keka workaround if they're being obstinate about it.

Answer (score 1):

If the Windows users are baffled by the resource fork information inside the zip-file you can simply remove that in the OSX Terminal:

```
zip -d name_of_zipfile.zip __MACOSX
```

This will delete the __MACOSX sub-folder (which contains the Mac specific resource fork info) from the specified zip-file.

Please note: __MACOSX is case-sensitive and starts with 2 underscore characters